# Finding badly written regex

Tags: java, python

To aid my learning of regex I'm attempting to improve upon existing regex's that have been written with poor performance.

Reading https://www.loggly.com/blog/five-invaluable-techniques-to-improve-regex-performance :

```
here are five regular expression techniques that can dramatically reduce processing time:

Character classes
Possessive quantifiers (and atomic groups)
Lazy quantifiers
Anchors and boundaries
Optimizing regex order
```

To automate the process of finding regex's written with poor performance I'm considering writing a script that will check each regex using above rules. For example, search for `[]` in order to check for character classes in each regex. If the regex does not contain a character class then it could be a candidate for performance optimization.

Are there other rule based methodologies that I can use to check regex performance.

Alternatively perhaps there is a Java / Python library that currently implements this functionality ?

Comment: Not all regexs should have character classes (or the others). You're going to have to learn to apply these concepts.  They're very powerful tools, but you'll have to use them yourself.  Any optimizations that can be applied universally are probably already built into whatever regex engine you're using.  implementing your own regex engine might be a valuable experience, but from what i understand they're fairly complicated.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks. I'm not attempting to implement my own regex engine, just automate the process of finding regex's that have poor performance. I doubt I can embed all domain knowledge of regex's into this search but perhaps there are common heuristics that I can check within regex's that will show a strong probability they will have poor performance ?